# Access variable i foreach

Tags: jquery, http-post, each

How to access a variable from $post function in $.each.

My Code:

```
var invoice_id;

$.post("<?=base_url()?>appointments/getId",{'code':code}, function(data) {

       var Obj = JSON.parse(data);
       console.log(Obj);
       invoice_id = Obj.invoice_id;

      });

$.each(Arr,function(i,Obj){
 invoice = invoice_id;
 console.log(invoice);

});
```

I need to access the invoice_id in $.each function.Currently am getting undefined.

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: You can put the $.each in callback function of $.Post

Comment: Have you console.log(invoice_id) in the callback of the post to make sure it isnt undefined in the response from the server?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `$.post` performs an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request, hence the result data should be handled by the callback function.

```
var invoice_id;

$.post("<?=base_url()?>appointments/getId",{'code':code}, function(data) {
   var Obj = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(Obj);
   invoice_id = Obj.invoice_id;

   $.each(Arr,function(i,Obj){
     invoice = invoice_id;
     console.log(invoice);
   });
});
```

Comment: But he has already set invoice_id globally. Chances are he is getting an undefined response from the server.

Comment: @wrxsti not really, the `$.post` is asynchronous, so at the time `$.each` uses the `invoice_id`, it's undefined, placing the `$.each` in the complete/done callback is the right way to do.

Comment: Thats also a very likely possibility.

Comment: @KingKing Yes, exactly.

Comment: @wrxsti: From both personal experience and browsing SO, this is almost always the issue ;)